# ParserError: Expected '(' but got identifier function OrderItem(uint _itemid, string _itemname) public returns(address){

Tags: solidity, contract-development, remix, contract-debugging

browser/Logistics.sol:60:14: ParserError: Expected '(' but got identifier
    function OrderItem(uint _itemid, string _itemname) public returns(address){
             ^-------^

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.24;

contract Logistics {

    //////////////////////DECLARATION/////////////////

      struct package{
         bool isuidgenerated;
         uint itemid;
         string itemname;
         string transitstatus;
         uint orderstatus; // 1 = ordered; 2 = in-transist; 3 = delivered; 4 = canceled
        address Owner;
         address customer;
         uint ordertime;

         address carrier1;
         uint carrier1_time;

         address carrier2;
         uint carrier2_time;

        address carrier3;
         uint carrier3_time;

}

     mapping (address => package) public packagemapping;
     mapping (address => bool) public carriers;

    ////////////////////DECLARATION END///////////////

////////////////////////MODIFIERS//////////////////

 constructor(){
     Owner = msg.sender;
 }
 modifier onlyOwner(){
     require(Owner = msg.sender);
     _;
 }
//////////////////////MODIFIERS END////////////////

///////////////MANAGE CARRIERS/////////////////////

function ManageCarriers(address _carrierAddress) onlyOwner public returns (string){

if (!carriers[_carrierAddress]){
      carriers[_carrierAddress] = true;
  } else {
      carriers[_carrierAddress] = false;     
  }
return "Carrier is updated";

///////////////MANAGE CARRIERS END /////////////////////



//////////////////////////ORDERITEM FUNCTION///////////////////////
    function OrderItem(uint _itemid, string _itemname) public returns(address){
        address uniqueId = address(sha256(msg.sender, now));

       packagemapping[uniqueId].isuidgenerated = true;
       packagemapping[uniqueId].itemid = _itemid;
       packagemapping[uniqueId].itemname = _itemname;
       packagemapping[uniqueId].transitstatus = "your package is ordered and is under processing";
       packagemapping[uniqueId].orderstatus = 1;

       packagemapping[uniqueId].customer = msg.sender;
       packagemapping[uniqueId].ordertime = now;

        return uniqueId;

}

/////////////////////////////ORDER FUNCTION END ///////////////////
}
```

Comment: You're at least missing `}`  at the end of function `ManageCarriers`. Please also format your code properly, it's very impossible to read currently

Comment: Also, by formatting your code properly you'd be able to see the error yourself...

Answer (score 1):

You were missing a `}` in `ManageCarriers` as @Lauri mentioned, also you declared `Owner` in a struct and then you are initializing it independently in constructor, that is also an error. Also please format you code properly before pasting here and use `<pre><code>` to enclose it.

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.24;

contract Logistics {

//////////////////////DECLARATION/////////////////


    address Owner;

  struct package{
     bool isuidgenerated;
     uint itemid;
     string itemname;
     string transitstatus;
     uint orderstatus; // 1 = ordered; 2 = in-transist; 3 = delivered; 4 = canceled
     address customer;
     uint ordertime;

     address carrier1;
     uint carrier1_time;

     address carrier2;
     uint carrier2_time;

    address carrier3;
     uint carrier3_time;
}

 mapping (address => package) public packagemapping;
 mapping (address => bool) public carriers;

////////////////////DECLARATION END///////////////
////////////////////////MODIFIERS//////////////////

constructor () public
{ 
    Owner = msg.sender; 

} 
modifier onlyOwner(){ 
    require(Owner == msg.sender); _; 

} //////////////////////MODIFIERS END////////////////

///////////////MANAGE CARRIERS/////////////////////

function ManageCarriers(address _carrierAddress) onlyOwner public returns (string){

if (!carriers[_carrierAddress]){ carriers[_carrierAddress] = true; } else { carriers[_carrierAddress] = false;
} return "Carrier is updated";
}

///////////////MANAGE CARRIERS END /////////////////////

//////////////////////////ORDERITEM FUNCTION///////////////////////
function OrderItem(uint _itemid, string _itemname) public returns(address){
    address uniqueId = address(sha256(abi.encodePacked(msg.sender, now)));
   packagemapping[uniqueId].isuidgenerated = true;
   packagemapping[uniqueId].itemid = _itemid;
   packagemapping[uniqueId].itemname = _itemname;
   packagemapping[uniqueId].transitstatus = "your package is ordered and is under processing";
   packagemapping[uniqueId].orderstatus = 1;

   packagemapping[uniqueId].customer = msg.sender;
   packagemapping[uniqueId].ordertime = now;

    return uniqueId;
}

/////////////////////////////ORDER FUNCTION END /////////////////// 

}
```

Comment: browser/Logistics.sol:60:10: ParserError: Expected '(' but got identifier
function OrderItem(uint _itemid, string _itemname) public returns(address){
         ^-------^

Comment: any one help me

Comment: @bhemeswararaoankireddy use the code I've pasted above or just add `}` at the end of `ManageCarriers` function, your code is missing that.